# Minimum Agents required for delivering product in warehouse

Tags: java, algorithm

Problem statement:

I have a list of `WareHouses`. `WareHouse` has two properties i.e. `openingTime`, `closingTime`.

```
public class WareHouse {

  private int startTime;
  private int endTime;
}
```

There are group of Agents whose responsibility is to deliver product to Warehouse,I need to calculate minimum number of Agents required who can deliver products to all warehouses.

Assumption: when a agent is delivering product to a particular warehouse say W1{1,2} he can only come out after a duration of 1 hour i.e closing time of warehouse.

> Warehouse{openingTime, closingTime}
>   w1{1,2},w2{2,4},w3{3,6},w4{9,11},w5{10,11}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    WareHouse w1 = new WareHouse(2, 4);
    WareHouse w2 = new WareHouse(1, 2);
    WareHouse w3 = new WareHouse(3, 6);
    WareHouse w4 = new WareHouse(10, 11);
    WareHouse w5 = new WareHouse(9, 11);
    List<WareHouse> wareHouses = new ArrayList<WareHouse>();
    wareHouses.add(w1);
    wareHouses.add(w2);
    wareHouses.add(w3);
    wareHouses.add(w4);
    wareHouses.add(w5);
}
```

Ideally, it requires 2 agents, so how to design algorithm for it?

**My approach:**

There would be a background job that will check status of all agents. Once a agent picks up a task , i will set it’s availability to false. Once it finished i will add him back to agent queue. However, my main challenge here is how to guess that agent has completed task, how can i simulate this event this will tell me task is over and it’s been 2 hours?

Comment: Have a global time, have that time elapse in some interval, give your Agents a `timeElapsed` method and if they are done they notify your system that they are done.

Comment: ok, i will try this approach

Comment: Is this just a homework task? Or it is an actual software? If the second, is it going to be a distributed one, where agents have their own app to pickup a task and set themselves free, or web, or ...? You need to tell more about your scope.

Comment: i was asked this question in one of my interviews, let's assume it's not a distributed one we need to assign tasks

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. How long does it take an agent to deliver something? Is the agent delivering between warehouses, or from a distribution point to a warehouse, or from a warehouse to some business? There isn't enough information in your question to give any type of suggestions.

Comment: I am asking how many minimum no of agents required such that they can deliver to all the warehouses within their open hours.Agent is delivering from distribution point to a warehouse

Comment: In your example 1 agent would manage, wouldn't it? He would enter the warehouses at the following times: 1, 2, 3, 9, 10 (i assume that they can travel between warehouses instantly).

Comment: diginoise , no once a agent is assigned  to a warehouse it would come out at closing time only. for example W{1,2} agent would enter at 1 and leave at 2 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate minimum number of agents, you don't need to simulate the delivery process. It's an interval partitioning problem and you can use a greedy algorithm. Look into https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pearson/04GreedyAlgorithms-2x2.pdf.

In your case, you may use the following agent class (you'll need getters for Warehouse variables since they are private - I didn't show that here):

```
public class Agent {
   int lastFinishTime;

   boolean isCompatibleWith(WareHouse x) {
      return x.startTime > lastFinishTime;
   }

   boolean scheduleWareHouse(WareHouse x) {
      lastFinishTime = x.endTime;
   }
}
```

You can then apply the interval partitioning algorithm as follows (while using a priority queue of agents, sorted based on lastFinishTime):

```
Sort warehouses by starting time so that s1 ≤ s2 ≤ ... ≤ sn.
d ← 0
for j = 1 to n {
 if (warehouse j is compatible with some agent k)
 schedule warehouse j to agent k
 else
 allocate a new agent d + 1
 schedule warehouse j to agent d + 1
 d ← d + 1
}
```

Complete implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Partition {


    public static class WareHouse {

          int startTime;
          int endTime;

          public WareHouse(int i, int j) {
              startTime=i;
              endTime=j;
          }
    }


    public static class Agent {
        int end;

        public Agent() {

        }

        public boolean isCompWith(WareHouse x) {
            return end <=x.startTime;
        }

        public void schedule(WareHouse x) {
            end=x.endTime;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String...args) {
        WareHouse w1 = new WareHouse(2, 4);
        WareHouse w2 = new WareHouse(1, 2);
        WareHouse w3 = new WareHouse(3, 6);
        WareHouse w4 = new WareHouse(10, 11);
        WareHouse w5 = new WareHouse(9, 11);
        List<WareHouse> wareHouses = new ArrayList<WareHouse>();
        wareHouses.add(w1);
        wareHouses.add(w2);
        wareHouses.add(w3);
        wareHouses.add(w4);
        wareHouses.add(w5);
        Collections.sort(wareHouses, new Comparator<WareHouse> (){
            public int compare(WareHouse x, WareHouse y) {
                return x.startTime - y.startTime;
            }
        });
        PriorityQueue<Agent> queue = 
                new PriorityQueue<Agent>(new Comparator<Agent>() {
                    public int compare(Agent x, Agent y) {
                        return x.end- y.end;
                    }
                });
        for(WareHouse x: wareHouses) {
            Agent a = queue.poll();
            if(a==null) {
                a=new Agent();
                a.schedule(x);
                queue.add(a);
            } 
            else if (a.isCompWith(x)) {
                a.schedule(x);
                queue.add(a);
            } else {
                Agent b = new Agent();
                b.schedule(x);
                queue.add(a);
                queue.add(b);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(queue.size());
    }
```

Comment: Hi, one quick thought let's suppose one agent was allocate to a store, once work is finished he should be deallocated too, so that we can get minimum no of agents. so how we are going to deallocate in this scenario, that's the main challenge

Comment: You don't need to deallocate the agent. You can simply use a priority queue to hold the agents, which sorts them based on the time they become available. Perhaps this video might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_G8hZYcKnI. I wrote interval scheduling in my answer instead of partitioning - will correct it.

Comment: I added the complete implementation. If you are actually working with scheduling the agents, you will certainly need to allocate/deallocate them. That is a different problem entirely and you can look into implementing timers. But to simply find the minimum number of agents, there is no need to simulate the actual sequence of events.

Comment: The step of changing the end time of the agent is, in essence, simulating their deallocation from the current warehouse and assignment to the next one.

Comment: Ye correct, priority queue is mocking that deallocation simulation which will make the agent available again, thanks for your solution.

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark if it contains the solution you needed. Thanks!